# suggestion with hadoop project

Tags: apache-kafka, flume

I am thinking to build something using big data. Ideally what I would like to do is:

take a .csv put it into flume, than kafka, perform n ETL and put back in Kafka, from kafka put into flume and then in hdfs. Once the infos are in hdfs I would like to perform a map reduce job or some hive queries and then chart whatever I want.

How can I put the .csv file into flume and save it to kafka? I have this piece of code but I am not sure if it works:

```
myagent.sources = r1
myagent.sinks = k1
myagent.channels = c1

myagent.sources.r1.type = spooldir
myagent.sources.r1.spoolDir = /home/xyz/source
myagent.sources.r1.fileHeader = true

myagent.sinks.k1.type = org.apache.flume.sink.kafka.KafkaSink

vmagent.channels.c1.type = memory
myagent.channels.c1.capacity = 1000
myagent.channels.c1.transactionCapacity = 100

myagent.sources.r1.channels = c1
myagent.sinks.k1.channel = c1
```

Any help or suggestions? And if this piece of code is correct, how to move on?

Thanks everyone!!

Answer (score 0):

Your Sink config is incomplete. Try :

`a1.sinks.k1.type = org.apache.flume.sink.kafka.KafkaSink`

`a1.sinks.k1.topic = mytopic`

`a1.sinks.k1.brokerList = localhost:9092`

`a1.sinks.k1.requiredAcks = 1`

`a1.sinks.k1.batchSize = 20`

`a1.sinks.k1.channel = c1`

https://flume.apache.org/FlumeUserGuide.html#kafka-sink